# LazyColumn inside Viewplager2 scroll issue

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager2, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

There is a Viewpager 2 with 5 tabs and each tab contains a fragment.

In one of these fragments, I have a compose view and also used
LazyColmn inside this fragment.
What happens is sometimes when I want to scroll the lazy column horizontally, the view pager will consume the event and the tab will change.

As I understand this is a known bug in ViewPager2 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136194634

And there are ways to handle this issue with RecyclerView like overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` for recyclerview, But for LazyColumn I couldn't find any solution.